# DAO pattern for both HTTP and database

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I am about to implement a DAO design pattern in my project and I understand that this is most commonly used to communicate with the database.

But since there is usually an interface and an implementation I can't help to think that this is can also be used for HTTP. i.e. you have a DAO implementation for CRUD against the database and another DAO implementation for accessing a CRUD API. But if it is also used like this, then what is the common way to solve the problem that you might not have delete permissions on the API?

Is this correct or why would I need an interface for this? or is it just to allow me to easily change database implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The DAO pattern is generally used to decouple different forms of data representation; for example, separate a database schema from Java application logic. Interfaces (in the sense I think you are discussing) are typically used to decouple the implementation of Java logic from its implementation. These two forms of decoupling are completely different, and there's no reason not to use both together, if that makes the design more maintainable or expressive. Even if Java code is intended to be general purpose (for example, in some reusable library), then I don't think it's obligatory to specify its behaviour by interfaces, although there are different views on this point.

As to your specific question: if you have Java methods that operate on data, and those operations might fail, then conventionally you would throw an exception. If you are using DAOs and part of your java logic is highly decoupled from the data storage implementation, then that logic might not even recognize "access denied" as a meaningful concept. In such cases you have to decouple the exceptions as well, and have your DAO logic throw a general "update failed" exception. That exception can carry the original exception ("access denied") that came from the specific storage implementation up to its caller, which may or may not be able to make any sense of it. One of the hazards of extensive decoupling is that error handling becomes increasingly non-specific the further you get from the source of the error.